# exterior pe gas line - shutoff valve type

Tags: natural-gas, fire-pit

Running a PE gas line in a trench to a fire pit. Straightforward, permitted and will be inspected. (I understand the concerns many express about gas line work, but i'll have a licensed plumber to verify the work.)

Question:
I would like to install a shutoff valve at the meter connection to allow me to isolate it from the existing under-house gas system. There are many valve choices and I'm trying to understand the differences between them.

When I started this project, I just assumed I would use a full port lever handled ball valve, similar to what I've used on my water supply. They are often specified as 600 wog. I understand that the wog designation is for liquids and that there are other standards for natural gas. So I'm trying to find an appropriate valve for an exterior application.

Grainger carries these apollo gas cocks. These seem to be the traditional valves used on gas lines.
[image]

Why would one use choose this over a ball valve?
Thanks.

Comment: This is the traditional gas valve. It depends on grease in the valve for sealing and smooth operation. The grease will over time dry out and so periodically (10 years? 20 years?) the valve must be disassembled and recharged with grease. (Probably an experienced plumber would do this quickly without shutting off the gas at the meter.) Newer ball valves don't require grease because the metal ball seals against a soft plastic surround. I think some codes now require that the newer ball valves be installed in original installation or when an appliance is changed.

Comment: Thank you, Jim.  Further research found a more familiar ball valve which is specified for LP Gas:    Apollo 80-100 Series Bronze LP-Gas Ball Valve